# Joint distribution of two minimums of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, self-learning

Let $Z_1, Z_2, Z_3$ independent RVs with exponential distribution$(\lambda = 1)$.

Let $X = \min \{Z_1,Z_3\}$ and $Y =\min \{Z_2,Z_3\}$.

I need to find $P(X>x,Y>y)$, $P(X=Y)$ and $E[X|Y=2]$.

I know that $P(X>x) = P(Z_1>x)P(Z_3>x)$ and $P(Y>y) = P(Z_2>y)P(Z_3>y)$. However I get stuck here because it seems X are Y are not independent.

How should I approach this? Should I be conditioning for all the possible orders of $Z_1, Z_2, Z_3$ (ex: $Z_1>Z_2>Z_3, Z_1>Z_3>Z_2$, etc)?

Comment: Well, it seems that $[X>x,Y>y]=[Z_1>x,Z_2>\max(x,y),Z_3>y]$, no?

Comment: Thanks! I was not seeing this. With it I was able to work out the rest!